# Changing stylesheet repeatedly in PyQt5 causes crash with no logs?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm making a gpio simulator in PyQt5 that shows red and green colors in each button depending on the state of a variable. Everything works fine, but sometimes it crashes with no logs at all.

I change the stylesheet this way:

```
class GpioUi(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.gpio_status = [False] * 12
        self.enabled_gpios = [False] * 12

        super(GpioUi, self).__init__() 
        uic.loadUi('gpio_mainwindow.ui', self) # Load the .ui file
        self.setFixedSize(194, 286)
        self.show()

        
        self.element_selector.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: self.update_element_selected(self.element_selector.currentText()))

        self.gpio_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(0, not self.gpio_status[0]))
        self.gpio_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(1, not self.gpio_status[1]))
        self.gpio_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(2, not self.gpio_status[2]))
        self.gpio_4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(3, not self.gpio_status[3]))
        self.gpio_5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(4, not self.gpio_status[4]))
        self.gpio_6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(5, not self.gpio_status[5]))
        self.gpio_7.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(6, not self.gpio_status[6]))
        self.gpio_8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(7, not self.gpio_status[7]))
        self.gpio_9.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(8, not self.gpio_status[8]))
        self.gpio_10.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(9, not self.gpio_status[9]))
        self.gpio_11.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(10, not self.gpio_status[10]))
        self.gpio_12.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_gpio_status(11, not self.gpio_status[11]))

        
        self.update_element_selected(self.element_selector.currentText())


    def update_gpio_status(self, position, value):
        self.gpio_status[position] = value
        button : QPushButton = self.findChild(QPushButton, f"gpio_{position+1}")
        if value and button.styleSheet() != GREEN:
            button.setStyleSheet(GREEN)
        elif not value and button.styleSheet() != RED:
            button.setStyleSheet(RED)
```

The issue is: I have a state where the pin is blinking once a second. Everything works fine but eventually (at a random moment) it crashes with no logs at all, as if the program ends.

Also if I comment the "setStyleSheet" line, it stops happening but, obviously, I don't get the colors indicating the state of the pin.

Comment: I can't speak about this issue, but a possible work-around this would be to use `setPalette` instead of `setStylesheet`, and to have palettes with the relevant background colors. This is also generally faster than setting the stylesheet ?

Comment: I see that you're using a threading Lock. Is it possible that, somewhere else, you're also trying to call `setStyleSheet()` (or access UI elements) from an external thread?